# Elasticsearch get field mapping for all fields without using asterisk (*)

Tags: elasticsearch

To get mapping for **all** fields in an index, I do this:

GET `http://localhost:9200/some_awesome_index/_mapping/field/*`

But I don't want to use the *.  Is there another way to get the same result without using a * ?  I have dynamic fields, so I can't use a comma-separated list of every single field I need (without having to use the *).

Comment: Why don't you want to use the *?

Comment: @eemp because requests are going through a proxy that won't allow * in the URL.

Comment: Do you have several types in your index or only a single one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the get the mapping for all the fields of all the types in an index, use

> GET /index name/_mapping

If you want to get the mapping for all the fields of a single type in an index, use

> GET/index name/type name/_mapping

Comment: I understand that those get mappings, but the format of the result of the two examples you gave is different from including ```/field/``` in the URL.  I was hoping to get the same format in the result as what I'm using above.  Thanks anyway though. :)

Comment: I feel it gives you a much precise mapping structure. If you are satisfied please accept the answer. :-)

Comment: It was probably vague in my question when I asked for "the same result", but I meant I wanted the same formatting/structure of the response that you get when using ```/field/```.  I had already tried the methods you'd suggested, but didn't want to use those because the formatting/structure of the response is different.  I was hoping that there would be something like ```_all``` that could be used instead of ```*```, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: yep. _all does not work. Let me know if you find a way to do it apart from the one mentioned. I guess documentation says no. :(